# calculating last 5 years from current date in hive

Tags: date, hive

I need to calculate some count based on the given time frame
I need to consider the dates between current date and last 5 years

```
select count(*) from table where (year(current_date) -year('2015-12-01')) < 5 ;
```

above query will give counts for last 5 years however it will consider only year part but I need exact counts considering days so if I write

```
 select count(*) from table where datediff(current_date,final_dt) <= 1825 ;
```

it won't consider the leap years if any in the last 5 years

so Is there any function in hive to calculate exact difference between two dates consider scenarios like leap years?

Comment: So basically, you want rows that fall between current date and a date that is 5 years in the past from current date, right?

Answer (score 1):

Use `add_months` function (assuming the dates should go back to `2013-05-25` with the current date being `2018-05-25`).

```
select count(*) 
from table
where final_dt >= add_months(current_date,-60) and final_dt <= current_date
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to calculate `count(*)` all records between `current_date` and a date which is 5 year in the past from `current_date`, in this case, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM table_1 WHERE date_column BETWEEN current_date AND to_date(CONCAT(YEAR(current_date) - 5, '-', MONTH(current_date), '-', DAY(current_date)));
```

And `SELECT datediff( current_date() ,to_date(CONCAT(YEAR(current_date) - 5, '-', MONTH(current_date), '-', DAY(current_date))));`

gives you `1826` (considering the fact that 2016 is a leap year).